# Android: Deleting specific row in database

Tags: android, sqlite

Sorry if this seems obvious. I'm trying to write a method to delete a row from a String showId. What would be the best way, and can Cursors only be used for Selects or also for Deletes and Updates?
These are the two methods I'm at so far:

```
public int deleteShowById1(String showId){
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM tblShows WHERE showId = '" + showId+"'", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return 1;
    } else
        return -1;
}

    public int deleteShowById2(String showId) {
    String table_name = "tblShows";
    String where = "showId='"+showId+"'";
    return db.delete(table_name, where, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use the second method (`db.delete`), as I think using `rawQuery` is frowned upon.

If you do a select, then loop through the cursor to do updates or deletes, that would make sense, but to pass a cursor to do the delete or update doesn't make sense to me, as the program won't know how to parse the cursor results to get the correct fields.

Answer (score 1):

As we know from mysql query, it is same here in android.

```
    String query = "DELETE FROM " +TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "  + COLUM_NAME+ " = " + "'"+VALUE +"'" ;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(query);
    db.close();
```

VALUE may or may not have single quotation depending on datatype.